# How do you collect all input values and send via $.post, without knowing the ID or Name Properties?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my first question so, be gentle. I have a form with inputs that are generated dynamically by the server. I have to collect all of the form data, then post it to the server, where it is then processed into a normalized view. My problem is, I do not know how to simply send all the values of my form inputs, using the name property as the name. I can handle it on the server in php by breaking out the input array. I just don't know how to create and send the array with jquery.

Here is the part of the form that is generated by the server:

```
<input type="text" name="Accessory Type" class="inputTypeAttrs">
```

The inputs are different based on a category selected by the user. The generated inputs will never have an id property and I can not know ahead of time, much about the inputs. They can also change over time. I can add a class to the inputs, but not an id.

I am using CodeIgniter on the back-end so I grab the input array using:

```
$this->input->post();
```

Iterating through the array and returning the data is easy with php. Should I just avoid using jquery and ajax with this altogether?

Comment: look into jQuery serialize [here](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery serialize for this. For example:

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
    $.post( "my/page/", $( this ).serializeArray(), function( data ) {
      console.log('Response is', data);
    });
});
```

The serializeArray will make an object literal from all your form input fields. This is then posted to the page you specify.